# How can I get this to call the images (digits) from another folder. It works when I put the code in the same folder as the images (digits)

Tags: javascript, image

How can I get this to call the images (digits) from another folder. It works when I put the code in the same folder as the images (digits).

```js
function getImg(num) {
  var digits = String(num).split(""),
    text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    text += '<img alt="' + digits[i] + '" src="' + digits[i] + '.gif" />';
  }
  return text;
}

CountDownTimer('02/19/2024 10:1 AM', 'countdown');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2024 10:1 AM', 'newcountdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
  var end = new Date(dt);

  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

      return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getImg(days) + 'days ' +
      getImg(hours) + 'hrs ' +
      getImg(minutes) + 'mins ' +
      getImg(seconds) + 'secs';
  }

  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div id="newcountdown"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried adding the web address on this line, but it didn't work.

```
  text += '<img alt="'+digits[i]+'" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/'+digits[i]+'.gif" />';
```

Comment: Just FYI, while adding `alt` attributes to images is a fine idea, with the way it's done here, the quantity "12 hrs 57 mins" will be read as "one two hrs five seven mins", which may or may not confuse someone...

Comment: I think your code should work, but it looks like your URL for the images is wrong. I tried going to https://okoutdoors.com/img/1.gif and got a 404 error.

Comment: Also on a modern JS note, don't use `+` to glue strings together, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), e.g. ```text += `<img alt="${digits[i]}" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/${digits[i]}.gif">`;```. (And you'll want to stop using `var` and switch to `let` for reassignable variables, and `const` for fixed variables)